# su authentication failure after setting new password

Tags: root, su

I compiled a new kernel(3.2) and I have it running on an ARM board.
I wanted to enable some params on the `/proc` directories. Therefore I have to be logged in as root.
Hence I did the following on my newly compiled system:

```
sudo passwd su
```

and set a new root password.

Then I logged in as root.
However I get the error message `su-Authentication failure`.

How do I solve this problem? Has this to do with the `/usr/bin` file permissions?

What setting should I change to be able to login as root?

Comment: `Then I logged in as root. However I get su-Authentication failure error message.`, were you doing root login or su login?

Comment: Why are you trying to change the password? You can't `sudo su -`?

Comment: Oops that really was a typo! I had done only sudo passwd root...

Answer (score 2):

the argument `passwd` takes is a username

```
sudo passwd root
```

if that doesn't work you should reboot into single user mode and change the password that way

Comment: could you please explain how I can reboot into this mode? although I reset the password SUCCESSFULLY, I cannot login as root with the new password. Please help

Comment: assuming you're using grub:to reboot into single user mode you reboot the machine and when the GRUB boot loader comes up you need to edit the command line to load the kernel and append a `1` after all the arguments

Comment: I fixed it. I had to set the sticky bit of the su binary! So when I did chmod +s /bin/su, I could "su" with the changed root password.Thanks for all your help

Comment: you could've also used `sudo -i` to gain root via sudo without elevating with `su`